# PDFKit, nodeJS merging two PDF files

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, node-pdfkit

does anyone have experience with PDFKit with NodeJS. Specifically, I'm trying to merge 2 PDF documents into 1, but I can't seem seem to get the content of the two PDFs properly with formatting inside the merged one.

Here's what I do:

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var fs = require('fs');

var doc = new PDFDocument();
var fileName = 'test.pdf';
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));

var file1 = '1.pdf';
var file2 = '2.pdf';

var stream1 = fs.createReadStream(file1);
doc.text(stream1);

doc.addPage();
var stream2 = fs.createReadStream(file2);
doc.text(stream2);

doc.end();
```

The output, that being test.pdf, should consist of a single pdf containing the contents of the 2 pdfs with the same formatting, but I'm only getting test.pdf with 2 pages, each consisting of a single line of "[Object object]". I can't seem to find how to redirect the content of the stream inside the doc.text() function.

Any idea on what I do wrong, how should I fix it?

Comment: hi Blitz. Did you get it to work? And How? Could you please share. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

[**It is not possible to merge two PDF documents with pdfkit!**](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/417#issuecomment-135062984)

You can use [pdftk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) for that purpose. The program offers a command line interface, which could merge two pdfs with the following command:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output merged.pdf
```