# merging 2 pdf with pdfkit in node

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfkit

This question has not been answered so I am asking again if someone has an idea on how to solve it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640533/pdfkit-nodejs-merging-two-pdf-files))

The following code

```
var doc = new PDFDocument();
var fileName = 'test.pdf';
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));

var file1 = '1.pdf';
var file2 = '2.pdf';

var stream1 = fs.createReadStream(file1);
doc.text(stream1);

doc.addPage();
var stream2 = fs.createReadStream(file2);
doc.text(stream2);

doc.end();
```

generates a pdf with [Object][Object].

So the question: is it possible to write the doc object with the streamed data from 1.pdf and 2.pdf and how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily merge two or more pdf-files with Pdftk Server.

> PDFtk Server is our command-line tool for working with PDFs. It is commonly used for client-side scripting or server-side processing of PDFs.

```
let input1 = './input1.pdf';
let input2 = './input2.pdf';
let output = './output.pdf';

require('child_process').exec(`pdftk ${input1} ${input2} cat output ${output}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    ...

});
```